# optimize this query

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

ms sql server 2008

[image]

```
SELECT Action.* 
FROM   Mailing 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategoryMailingBunch 
         ON Mailing.MailingID = ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingID 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategory 
         ON ActionCategoryMailingBunch.ActionCategoryID = 
            ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID 
       INNER JOIN Action 
         ON ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID = Action.ActionCategoryID 
WHERE  ( Mailing.MailingID = 7 ) 
       AND ( Mailing.MailingID NOT IN (SELECT MailingID 
                                       FROM   MailingReport) ) 
       AND ( Action.ActionID NOT IN (SELECT ActionID 
                                     FROM   MailingReport) ) 
       AND ( ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingBunchStatusID = 4 )
```

especially this block

```
(Mailing.MailingID NOT IN (SELECT MailingID FROM  MailingReport)) 
AND (Action.ActionID NOT IN (SELECT ActionID FROM  MailingReport))
```

Comment: If that's what you need semantically then not sure what you expect us to do with your query! If you are having performance issues please post the execution plan and definition of all relevant tables including indexes. Though as you are only selecting columns from `Action` you might want to use `EXISTS` rather than `JOIN`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below code in the select statement

```
Left Join MailingReport MR on MR.ActionID = Mailing.MailingID
```

Add the below code in Where clause

```
(MR.ActionID is null)
```

Performance upgrade due to following block

```
(Mailing.MailingID NOT IN (SELECT MailingID FROM  MailingReport))
```

Final Query

```
SELECT Action.* 
FROM   Mailing 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategoryMailingBunch 
         ON Mailing.MailingID = ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingID 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategory 
         ON ActionCategoryMailingBunch.ActionCategoryID = 
            ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID 
       INNER JOIN Action 
         ON ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID = Action.ActionCategoryID 
         Left Join MailingReport MR on MR.ActionID = Mailing.MailingID
WHERE  ( Mailing.MailingID = 7 ) 
       --AND ( Mailing.MailingID NOT IN (SELECT MailingID 
       --                                FROM   MailingReport) ) 
       AND
       (MR.ActionID is null)
       AND ( Action.ActionID NOT IN (SELECT ActionID 
                                     FROM   MailingReport) ) 
       AND ( ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingBunchStatusID = 4 )
```

Similarly you can do for the second block
Performance due to second block

```
AND (Action.ActionID NOT IN (SELECT ActionID FROM  MailingReport))
```

Final Query for both blocks

```
SELECT Action.* 
FROM   Mailing 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategoryMailingBunch 
         ON Mailing.MailingID = ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingID 
       INNER JOIN ActionCategory 
         ON ActionCategoryMailingBunch.ActionCategoryID = 
            ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID 
       INNER JOIN Action 
         ON ActionCategory.ActionCategoryID = Action.ActionCategoryID 
         Left Join MailingReport MR on MR.ActionID = Mailing.MailingID
         Left Join MailingReport MRA on MRA.ActionID = Action.ActionID
WHERE  ( Mailing.MailingID = 7 ) 
       AND
       (MR.ActionID is null)
       AND
       (MRA.ActionID is null)
       AND ( ActionCategoryMailingBunch.MailingBunchStatusID = 4 )
```

Comment: [Converting NOT IN to LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is not an optimisation](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/)

Comment: In the past I had similar issue with my query. The above was the corrective action to resolve it. According to my knowledge, the In query internally acts as a loop which I am here avoiding it.

Comment: This was my experience in past.